# Racket type annotations in for/list using in-query (DB calls)

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to read data from a database in typed Racket and convert it to a list of structures. The code below is the untyped version that works perfectly. This is the smallest bit I can make that demonstrates the problem.

```
#lang racket

(require db)

(define dbc (sqlite3-connect #:database "dmdb.sqlite3" #:mode 'read/write))

(struct player (name size str dex con base-hp current-hp base-ac attack) #:mutable)

(define get-players
  (lambda (c)
    (for/list
        ([(n s str dex con bhp chp bac attack)
            (in-query c "select * from players")])
      (player n s str dex con bhp chp bac attack))))
```

The typed version of the procedure is as shown below:

```
#lang type/racket
(require typed/db)

(: get-players (-> Connection (Listof player)))
(define get-players
  (lambda (c)
    (for/list
        ([(n s str dex con bhp chp bac attack)
            (in-query c "select * from players")])
      (player n s str dex con bhp chp bac attack))))
```

When I try to compile it in typed Racket I receive some strange error messages:

```
Type Checker: Expression should produce 9 values, but produces 1 values of
types SQL-Datum in: (for/list (((n s str dex con bhp chp bac attack
(in-query c "select * from players"))) (player n s str dex con bhp chp bac
attack))
```

Again, the code works perfectly as long as it is not typed.

Comment: Where are you getting the `Connection` type from?

Comment: I forgot to include the #lang typed/racket and (require typed/db) in the second example. I've edited the post to correct that. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. I have an answer now, writing it up.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like even though the syntax of `for` in typed racket supports multiple values, you cannot actually type check a sequence of multiple values in `typed/racket`. You can, however, convert a sequence of values into a list with the [`in-values-sequence`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-values-sequence#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-values-sequence%29%29). From there, you can use `define-values` to split out the list back into values, or just use the list inline. For the function you gave, this would look like:

```
(: get-players (-> Connection (Listof player)))
(define (get-players c)
  (for/list ([a (in-values-sequence (in-query c "select * from players"))])
    (player (list-ref a 0)
            (list-ref a 1)
            (list-ref a 2)
            (list-ref a 3)
            (list-ref a 4)
            (list-ref a 5)
            (list-ref a 6)
            (list-ref a 7)
            (list-ref a 8))))
```

I suspect this might have an effect on your program's performance, but I can't say for sure what. If you want to create a sequence of multiple values, you could ask the people on [the racket mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users/) for help, as they likely know something I don't.

Comment: Interesting solution, but at least in my case it generates errors such as

Type Checker: Polymorphic function `list-ref' could not be applied to arguments:
Argument 1:
  Expected: (Listof a)
  Given:    (Listof SQL-Datum)
Argument 2:
  Expected: Integer
  Given:    Zero

Result type:     a
Expected result: String
 in: (list-ref a 0)

Comment: (assert (list-ref a 0) string?)
            (assert (list-ref a 1) string?)  seem to fix the first two, but trying it with integer? gives me Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Integer
  given: (U Inexact-Real Integer) in: (assert (list-ref a 2) integer?)

Comment: It compiles with casts but it bombs in execution: in-query: broke its own contract
  promised: a sequence of 1 values
  produced: 9 values
 values: '("phred" "medium" 14 12 12 12 12 18 1)

Comment: Ahh...hmm...it is hard for me to test this as I don't have a matching database right now.

Comment: The database is all of 5KB long at the moment. If you want it, you can contact me at gowinggl (AT) nova.edu (I'm a professor there) I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Sure. I'll ping you in a few hours when I get home.

Comment: Oh, I am leif -at- leif.pl

Comment: To assert something is an Integer, you need to use the predicate `exact-integer?` since the TR Integer type corresponds to exact integers only.

Comment: Oh, this is a bug in `typed/db`. The `in-query` function assumes only one value is returned, which is not the case. Would you be willing to file a bug report? (If not I would be happy to do it.)

Comment: As for a workaround, it might be possible to use the untyped `in-query`, I'm testing that out now.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Leif Andersen I found an answer. Below is the smallest bit of code I could create that allowed me to test my solution. It involves using `query-rows` instead of `in-query` to extract the data and then manipulating the resulting list of vectors.

```
#lang typed/racket
(require typed/db/base typed/db/sqlite3)


; for testing - cut and paste into interactions window
(define dbc (sqlite3-connect #:database "dmdb.sqlite3" #:mode 'read/write))

(struct player ([name : String] [size : String]
                [str : Integer] [dex : Integer] [con : Integer] [base-hp : Integer]
                [current-hp : Integer]
                [base-ac : Integer] [attack : Integer]) #:mutable )

(define lv (query-rows dbc "select * from players"))

(define ll : (Listof (Listof SQL-Datum))
    (for/list ((v lv))
      (vector->list v)))

(: lv->ll (-> (Listof (Vectorof SQL-Datum)) (Listof (Listof SQL-Datum))))
(define lv->ll
  (lambda (llv)
    (for/list ((v llv))
      (vector->list v))))

(: list->player (-> (Listof SQL-Datum) player))
(define list->player
  (lambda (a)
    (player (cast (list-ref a 0) String)
            (cast (list-ref a 1) String)
            (cast (list-ref a 2) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 3) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 4) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 5) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 6) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 7) Integer)
            (cast (list-ref a 8) Integer))))

(: list->playerlist (-> (Listof (Listof SQL-Datum)) (Listof player)))
(define list->playerlist
  (lambda (l)
    (for/list ((p l))
      (list->player p))))

(: listvectors->playerlist (-> (Listof (Vectorof SQL-Datum)) (Listof player)))
(define listvectors->playerlist
  (lambda (l)
    (list->playerlist (lv->ll l))))

(disconnect dbc)
```

I know that casts are considered ugly in some circles, but I needed to force the data types and I'm trusting that no-one is going to screw with the database once the program's out there. If they mess up their DB, it's their own problem, I guess.